# Flask return CSV in microservices

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask API that returns a csv like so:

```
    return send_file(
        f,
        attachment_filename="submission_report.csv",
        as_attachment=True,
        mimetype='text/csv'
    )
```

However, I have another flask service, which calls the above API, and returns the above response to the client. The resource for this app does something like this:

```
return requests.get(csv_api_route)
```

However, this returns an error like so:

```
   {
      "filename": "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py",
      "function_name": "default",
      "line_number": 184,
      "text": "raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"
    }
```

Is there a way to have an intermediate flask app return such a response to the client?

Comment: Can you show request and response HTTP headers (using browser or  requests from Python shell or tools like httpie)?

Comment: Does your API layer automatically serialize responses to JSON?  Are the clients consuming your API going to expect JSON too, or will they expect a streaming `text/csv` response?